New Outlook: Can existing rules be reapplied?
I am using the new version of Outlook (‘The new Outlook’ in MS-speak). I have created several rules and would now like them to be reapplied to my inbox.
I know that when you create a rule, you can apply it directly, but this does not work, if you create several rules at once and the last ‘rule run’ has not yet been completed.
When you create a rule, it takes quite a long time for Outlook to complete the ‘sorting’ process. If you create further rules during this time, they cannot be executed automatically, so I would like to trigger this later.
Does anyone have a good answer? VBA solutions would also be fine

What sort of account? New Outlook doesn't have a macro engine to VBA is not an option. If this is a Microsoft/M365 account you can open the Outlook.com web app and your able to quickly run the more involved rules as you please in that interface.

That works, yes. Though running them one by one there takes quite a bit time :( Maybe 25k mails is a bit overdone :)
But i will try that if noone has a good idea how to run all rules at once :)

According to your description, i understand that you want to run all rules manually in New Outlook for Windows, right?
If so, as i mentioned in this thread, it's not available in New Outlook, we can only run a rule once. You can vote for the feedback and hope Microsoft will notice this.

Arg, why, oh, why :) Voting just now. Thanks for letting me know!

The new outlook is based on webmail. Although I'm not really a fan of the new outlook, and as such am not using it, I know how to do this in webmail.
In webmail, go to account, settings, and locate your rules.
At the right of your rule, there's a play button. After you click it, that rule is now run. Do note, running a rule takes quite a bit of time, and you can only run one rule at a time.
If you don't see it in the new outlook, consider using webmail. It will have the same rules, so it doesn't really matter where you execute it.
